# Is it possible to write Oracle External Stored Procedures in Rust?

Tags: oracle, rust

The supported languages are C and Java. Could Rust compile to a static DLL that is compatible with the Oracle interface?

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_externproc.htm#ADFNS010

Comment: An interesting alternative with Oracle DB 21c is to use JavaScript _in_ the DB (like PL/SQL can be used), see https://blogs.oracle.com/database/post/introducing-oracle-database-21c

Comment: @ChristopherJones: Thanks, but I am looking specifically for Rust as this relates to performance critical calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C functions are supported you can do this like explained [here](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/rust-with-c.html).

Basically you specify in the `Cargo.toml`, that you want your library to be compiled into a DLL:

```
[lib]
name = "your_library_name"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

and then you can write your Rust functions like this:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_function_to_be_called_from_plsql() {

}
```

### Additional Info

You should also be able to do the reverse (which is explained in the linked docs) and call a PLSQL Procedure compiled into a DLL from Rust, also by using the C interface, like so:

```
#[link(name = "mylib")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn my_exported_plsql_function();
}
```